# Tags only for syntax?

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

There could be some tags that would only be there as a hint for the syntax highlighting. For instance, `syntax-java`.
This would be for the cases when the question is not specific to a language, nor the other tags are. For instance, an Excel makro could be written in VBscript and JavaScript, but the question is not about those, and adding the `javascript` tag would kind of clutter the `javascript` questions space.
So one would add `syntax-javascript`.

These tags wouldn't be shown in the UI unless editing. They wouldn't be counted into the 5 tags maximum. There could only be 2 `syntax-*` tags on a question.

Using the `<!-- ... -->` syntax is a bit cumbersome. This would be more convenient.

WDYT?

Edit: Ok this seems not to resonate here (at least not now), so I've posted [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345113/how-to-prevent-cluttering-language-tags-with-not-real-language-related-questions).

Comment: How would it know which `syntax-` tag to apply to which code block?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, the same way it knows which one to apply now. Somehow it does.

Answer (score 6):

Using tags - which are limited to only five per question, and should *strongly* correlate to the language you want to ask about - to indicate what the syntax highlighting should be in a question or its subsequent answers which *may* have multiple languages (which would be a very strong smell of an off-topic question, but I digress) - would be more cumbersome than simply using the HTML-esque comment highlight syntax.

Comment: Multiple languages are common in the web development arena (html, css, javascript, perhaps a server-side language too).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan:  Yes, but a question that includes *all* of those languages at once is very, very likely too broad.

Comment: @Makoto, it's quite common to contain all those languages. Take Angular 2  - TypeScript, JavaScript, JSON, HTML can all be in one question without being offtopic. Another typical example could be Java, SQL, HQL, XML and .properties.

Comment: @OndraŽižka:  If a question contained ***all*** of that at once, I'd have serious questions about its quality.  It wouldn't sound like it's focused enough to be well-answerable.

Comment: How is the `<!-- ...` less cumbersome than auto-filled tags? Which can also be edited without editing the whole question, so user can edit after posting when he sees the auto highlight didn't match any of the tags?

Comment: The main point is that a question with disparate languages with no relation one with the other enough that the pretify code couldn't take the hint may have some problems.

Comment: @Makoto, Java EE code, especially the older versions of Java EE, can easily span over many syntaxes. Seems like you don't have much experience with that, true? A complex Hibernate question can contain XML entity descriptor, properties config, Java entity class, and then HQL translated into SQL. No big deal, a real life situation.

Comment: @OndraŽižka:  I've worked professionally with these languages.  This doesn't change my criticism of your suggestion, since it's not entirely likely that someone would include that sort of thing - unless they were listing their HQL query and schema *and* it would have to be relevant to the question at hand.